# how to avoid escaping of < and > in SoapUI

Tags: xml, soapui

Are there any propertes(in soapui), config of which allows to avoid changing any < or > in response xmls for < and >  ?

Example of response:

```
<RESPONSEXML>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?&gt;
</RESPONSEXML>
```

But I want to see

```
<RESPONSEXML><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
</RESPONSEXML>
```

in response.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The desired output you mentioned is not a well-formed xml, because you wanted to have nested xml, not right. The xml you are getting  is valid which has `&lt;` instead of `<`, then it becomes string. By the way, what is your objective? Please see https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/working-with-cdata.html

Comment: yep, its just an example, cutted part from response. forgot to mention some points: 1) its response from jdbc request, we just try to receive xmls saved in DB, so 2) my goal is to receive good-looking responses from DB; 3) of course, I can use any sql "navigator" etc, and receive that < > instantly, but  Im just interesting, is it possible to do that in SoapUI and not to jump from one tool to another

Comment: Like mentioned it earlier, what you are asking is not valid/correct, because, xml  will no more well-formed by doing so. Hence you will not be able to process it further if needed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is invalid

Comment: @Dmitry , have you already connected to db and run query through soapui? what is the response you get when you run query through some other tool? is it the second one you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

As @Rao comments if you want to have a nesteds XML it's necessary to escape `<` and `>` of the internal one to have a well formed XML.

Anyway I suppose that you want for example to get the nested one to work with in another testStep. To do so you can simply parse your XML with a `new XmlSlurper.parseText()` and then apply `toString()` method on your `GPathResult`. You'll have your nested XML as string unescaped. It's a little tricky but it works on SOAPUI for your specific case (then you can parse it again a do whatever you want with it):

```java
import groovy.xml.*
def response = '''<RESPONSEXML>
        &lt;root&gt;
            &lt;someNode&gt;value&lt;/someNode&gt;
        &lt;/root&gt;
</RESPONSEXML>'''
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response)
def xmlStr = xml.toString()
log.info xmlStr // prints "<root><someNode>value</someNode></root>"
// now you can do whatever you want with it... 
// for example parsing it again and getting some values...
def nestedXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlStr)
log.info nestedXml.someNode // prints "valid"
```